# Text is not centered on small devices

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I am doing a front end challenge using HTML and CSS, In the website I have this text:

[image]

The above image Is a screenshot from a web view, I need to keep the text centered horizontally when you open the website on a mobile device.

Current output:

[image]

---

As you can see in the images, the smaller the screen will get the more the text will go to the left of the screen

### Things that I have done so far:

I have seen [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/centering-things-with-css-flexbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element) that I can do it like this:

```
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
```

SO I have tried to do so:

```
<p class="top-paragprph colorWhite bold">All your files in one secure location,<br> accessible anywhere.</p>
```

```
.top-paragprph{
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But it did not work for me.

From what I have been reading it seems like flex is the modern and easy way to do so, why on my example the text is not centered on a smaller screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to center the paragraph and also that your navbar is also 100% I would guess that the image is going outside of your body element and making it looks like this is not centered.
You can fix this by giving the image `max-width: 100%;`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `text-align: center;` or maybe if you are using bootstrap, add the class `text-center` your `<p></p>` tag

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this did not solved my problem

Comment: I am not using bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

https://codepen.io/critingz/pen/PomJRov

```
.holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

have a holder div that contains the text. The holder div can be display: flex;, justify-content: center;

Comment: Thank you for answering but this did not solved my problem

Comment: you must have something else that breaks it in your code because that's a pretty common way for centering with flexbox and it works

Answer (score 2):

The `display: flex;` should go on a parent element, like so:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="top-paragprph colorWhite bold">All your files in one secure location,<br> accessible anywhere.</p>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works how you want it to.

Comment: I have tried this but this did not fixed the problem

Comment: Could you describe the behaviour you expect? Add it to the question to help everyone out

Comment: If this was not clear  - I need the text to be centered horizontally on small devices, as for now it just sticks to the left of the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto
}
```

Set width to p element and then set margin auto.